# Combining ARIMA and BP for project

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, backpropagation

This is my first post.

I have to implement a model combining both ARIMA and BP to predict CPU Utilization based on previous data and reduce error. After implementing this ARIMA model I'm getting MSE of 1.6. I want to reduce it to below 0.8. Also I'm not sure on how to combine these 2 models.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. It's really important to me.

My data is in timestamp. I'm not sure how to bring that to the BP model. I can't attach my data as there's no option to attach a CSV file. Again ,please help.

ARIMA model-

```
import warnings
from pandas import read_csv
from pandas import datetime
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

# evaluate an ARIMA model for a given order (p,d,q)
def evaluate_arima_model(X, arima_order):
    # prepare training dataset
    train_size = int(len(X) * 0.66)
    train, test = X[0:train_size], X[train_size:]
    history = [x for x in train]
    # make predictions
    predictions = list()
    for t in range(len(test)):
        model = ARIMA(history, order=arima_order)
        model_fit = model.fit(disp=0)
        yhat = model_fit.forecast()[0]
        predictions.append(yhat)
        history.append(test[t])
    # calculate out of sample error
    error = mean_squared_error(test, predictions)
    return error

# evaluate combinations of p, d and q values for an ARIMA model
def evaluate_models(dataset, p_values, d_values, q_values):
    dataset = dataset.astype('float32')
    best_score, best_cfg = float("inf"), None
    for p in p_values:
        for d in d_values:
            for q in q_values:
                order = (p,d,q)
                try:
                    mse = evaluate_arima_model(dataset, order)
                    if mse < best_score:
                        best_score, best_cfg = mse, order
                    print('ARIMA%s MSE=%.3f' % (order,mse))
                except:
                    continue
    print('Best ARIMA%s MSE=%.3f' % (best_cfg, best_score))

# load dataset
def parser(x):
    return datetime.strptime(x, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M')
series = read_csv('/home/techmadmin/Desktop/Data.csv', header=0, parse_dates=[0], index_col=0, squeeze=True, date_parser=parser)
# evaluate parameters
p_values = range(0,10)
d_values = range(0,3)
q_values = range(0,3)
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
evaluate_models(series.values, p_values, d_values, q_values)
```

And BP model where I'm not able to input timestamp data:

```
# Backprop on the Seeds Dataset
from random import seed
from random import randrange
from random import random
from csv import reader
from math import exp

# Load a CSV file
def load_csv(filename):
    dataset = list()
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        csv_reader = reader(file)
        for row in csv_reader:
            if not row:
                continue
            dataset.append(row)
    return dataset

# Convert string column to float
def str_column_to_float(dataset, column):
    for row in dataset:
        row[column] = float(row[column].strip())

# Convert string column to integer
def str_column_to_int(dataset, column):
    class_values = [row[column] for row in dataset]
    unique = set(class_values)
    lookup = dict()
    for i, value in enumerate(unique):
        lookup[value] = i
    for row in dataset:
        row[column] = lookup[row[column]]
    return lookup

# Find the min and max values for each column
def dataset_minmax(dataset):
    minmax = list()
    stats = [[min(column), max(column)] for column in zip(*dataset)]
    return stats

# Rescale dataset columns to the range 0-1
def normalize_dataset(dataset, minmax):
    for row in dataset:
        for i in range(len(row)-1):
            row[i] = (row[i] - minmax[i][0]) / (minmax[i][1] - minmax[i][0])

# Split a dataset into k folds
def cross_validation_split(dataset, n_folds):
    dataset_split = list()
    dataset_copy = list(dataset)
    fold_size = int(len(dataset) / n_folds)
    for i in range(n_folds):
        fold = list()
        while len(fold) < fold_size:
            index = randrange(len(dataset_copy))
            fold.append(dataset_copy.pop(index))
        dataset_split.append(fold)
    return dataset_split

# Calculate accuracy percentage
def accuracy_metric(actual, predicted):
    correct = 0
    for i in range(len(actual)):
        if actual[i] == predicted[i]:
            correct += 1
    return correct / float(len(actual)) * 100.0

# Evaluate an algorithm using a cross validation split
def evaluate_algorithm(dataset, algorithm, n_folds, *args):
    folds = cross_validation_split(dataset, n_folds)
    scores = list()
    for fold in folds:
        train_set = list(folds)
        train_set.remove(fold)
        train_set = sum(train_set, [])
        test_set = list()
        for row in fold:
            row_copy = list(row)
            test_set.append(row_copy)
            row_copy[-1] = None
        predicted = algorithm(train_set, test_set, *args)
        actual = [row[-1] for row in fold]
        accuracy = accuracy_metric(actual, predicted)
        scores.append(accuracy)
    return scores

# Calculate neuron activation for an input
def activate(weights, inputs):
    activation = weights[-1]
    for i in range(len(weights)-1):
        activation += weights[i] * inputs[i]
    return activation

# Transfer neuron activation
def transfer(activation):
    return 1.0 / (1.0 + exp(-activation))

# Forward propagate input to a network output
def forward_propagate(network, row):
    inputs = row
    for layer in network:
        new_inputs = []
        for neuron in layer:
            activation = activate(neuron['weights'], inputs)
            neuron['output'] = transfer(activation)
            new_inputs.append(neuron['output'])
        inputs = new_inputs
    return inputs

# Calculate the derivative of an neuron output
def transfer_derivative(output):
    return output * (1.0 - output)

# Backpropagate error and store in neurons
def backward_propagate_error(network, expected):
    for i in reversed(range(len(network))):
        layer = network[i]
        errors = list()
        if i != len(network)-1:
            for j in range(len(layer)):
                error = 0.0
                for neuron in network[i + 1]:
                    error += (neuron['weights'][j] * neuron['delta'])
                errors.append(error)
        else:
            for j in range(len(layer)):
                neuron = layer[j]
                errors.append(expected[j] - neuron['output'])
        for j in range(len(layer)):
            neuron = layer[j]
            neuron['delta'] = errors[j] * transfer_derivative(neuron['output'])

# Update network weights with error
def update_weights(network, row, l_rate):
    for i in range(len(network)):
        inputs = row[:-1]
        if i != 0:
            inputs = [neuron['output'] for neuron in network[i - 1]]
        for neuron in network[i]:
            for j in range(len(inputs)):
                neuron['weights'][j] += l_rate * neuron['delta'] * inputs[j]
            neuron['weights'][-1] += l_rate * neuron['delta']

# Train a network for a fixed number of epochs
def train_network(network, train, l_rate, n_epoch, n_outputs):
    for epoch in range(n_epoch):
        for row in train:
            outputs = forward_propagate(network, row)
            expected = [0 for i in range(n_outputs)]
            expected[row[-1]] = 1
            backward_propagate_error(network, expected)
            update_weights(network, row, l_rate)

# Initialize a network
def initialize_network(n_inputs, n_hidden, n_outputs):
    network = list()
    hidden_layer = [{'weights':[random() for i in range(n_inputs + 1)]} for i in range(n_hidden)]
    network.append(hidden_layer)
    output_layer = [{'weights':[random() for i in range(n_hidden + 1)]} for i in range(n_outputs)]
    network.append(output_layer)
    return network

# Make a prediction with a network
def predict(network, row):
    outputs = forward_propagate(network, row)
    return outputs.index(max(outputs))

# Backpropagation Algorithm With Stochastic Gradient Descent
def back_propagation(train, test, l_rate, n_epoch, n_hidden):
    n_inputs = len(train[0]) - 1
    n_outputs = len(set([row[-1] for row in train]))
    network = initialize_network(n_inputs, n_hidden, n_outputs)
    train_network(network, train, l_rate, n_epoch, n_outputs)
    predictions = list()
    for row in test:
        prediction = predict(network, row)
        predictions.append(prediction)
    return(predictions)

# Test Backprop on Seeds dataset
seed(1)
# load and prepare data
filename = '/home/techmadmin/Desktop/Data.csv'
dataset = load_csv(filename)
for i in range(len(dataset[0])-1):
    str_column_to_float(dataset, i)
# convert class column to integers
str_column_to_int(dataset, len(dataset[0])-1)
# normalize input variables
minmax = dataset_minmax(dataset)
normalize_dataset(dataset, minmax)
# evaluate algorithm
n_folds = 5
l_rate = 0.3
n_epoch = 500
n_hidden = 5
scores = evaluate_algorithm(dataset, back_propagation, n_folds, l_rate, n_epoch, n_hidden)
print('Scores: %s' % scores)
print('Mean Accuracy: %.3f%%' % (sum(scores)/float(len(scores))))
```